# How to access config.yml parameters in OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, config, hwioauthbundle

We are using HWIOAuhtBundle for authentication so have a such user provider interface:

```
    class OAuthUserProvider implements 
          UserProviderInterface , OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface
    {
      ...
      public function loadUserByUsername($username)
      {
         ...
      }
      public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
      {
         ...
      }
   }
```

Is there the way to access parameters specified in config.yml in methods of OAuthUserProvider class, for instance the facebook app id?

```
hwi_oauth:
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           %fb_app%
```

or how to access the ServiceContainer? And then get parms this way:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to pass it as a parameter of OAuthUserProvider constructor.

1)Add an argument to the service  with a correct parameter name.

```
;services.yml

services:
     my_user.oauth_user_provider: 
         class: %my_user.oauth_user_provider.class%
         arguments: [%facebook_secret%]
```

2)Add an argument to the class ctor.

```
//OAuthUserProvider.php

class OAuthUserProvider implements 
      UserProviderInterface , OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($secret)
    {
       ...
    }
...
}
```